# Issue with XLSX2CSV API, it is appending .0 to an integer value(for example 10: 10.0)

Tags: java, apache-poi

*We are facing a problem with Export Excel in CSV Format using POI libraries.
When we use XLSX2CSV api, it is appending .0 to an integer value (ex: 10.0). 
This can be seen in any Text Editor (Not in Excel).*

```
    XLSX2CSV xlsx2csv = new XLSX2CSV(pkg, ps, 2);
    xlsx2csv.process();
```

Please, respond if you know / come across the solution.